# Consulta SQL se queda corta

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos en la que tengo entre otras, 3 tablas. La primera contiene datos de los usuarios, en la segunda la relacion que tiene una carrera de una universidad con sus asignaturas, y la ultima que contiene las propias asignaturas.

Total que tendria algo asi:

```
    mysql> describe users;
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
    | Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
    | id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
    | name       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
    | email      | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                |
    | password   | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
    | id_uni     | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
    | id_car     | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
    | created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
    7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> describe unicars;
    +--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id           | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | id_uni       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | id_car       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | id_asig      | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | cuatrimestre | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | ano          | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> describe asignaturas;
    +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | asignatura | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

El contenido de dichas tablas es el siguiente:

```
    mysql> select * from users;
    +----+---------+---------+----------+--------+--------+---------------------+
    | id | name    | email   | password | id_uni | id_car | created_at          |
    +----+---------+---------+----------+--------+--------+---------------------+
    |  1 | k1k4ss0 | jaja@gg | password |      1 |      1 | 2019-01-20 22:53:49 |
    +----+---------+---------+----------+--------+--------+---------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> select * from unicars;
    +----+--------+--------+---------+--------------+-----+
    | id | id_uni | id_car | id_asig | cuatrimestre | ano |
    +----+--------+--------+---------+--------------+-----+
    |  1 |      1 |      1 |       1 |            1 |   2 |
    |  2 |      1 |      1 |       2 |            1 |   2 |
    |  3 |      1 |      1 |       3 |            1 |   2 |
    |  4 |      1 |      1 |       4 |            1 |   2 |
    |  5 |      1 |      1 |       5 |            1 |   2 |
    |  6 |      1 |      1 |       6 |            2 |   2 |
    |  7 |      1 |      1 |       7 |            2 |   2 |
    |  8 |      1 |      1 |       8 |            2 |   2 |
    |  9 |      1 |      1 |       9 |            2 |   2 |
    | 10 |      1 |      1 |      10 |            2 |   2 |
    +----+--------+--------+---------+--------------+-----+
    10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> select * from asignaturas;
    +----+---------------------------------------------+
    | id | asignatura                                  |
    +----+---------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | Sistemas Operativos                         |
    |  2 | Ingles Tecnico                              |
    |  3 | Estructura de Computadores                  |
    |  4 | Estadistica                                 |
    |  5 | Computabilidad y Algoritmia                 |
    |  6 | Redes y Sistemas Distribuidos               |
    |  7 | Codigo Deontologico y Aspectos Legales      |
    |  8 | Algoritmos y Estructuras de Datos Avanzadas |
    |  9 | Administracion de Sistemas                  |
    | 10 | Fundamentos de Ingenieria del Software      |
    +----+---------------------------------------------+
    10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> select * from unis;
    +----+--------------------------+
    | id | universidad              |
    +----+--------------------------+
    |  1 | Universidad de la Laguna |
    +----+--------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

El tema es que no encuentro la forma de hacer una consulta en la que me muestre para un usuario todas las asignaturas de su carrera y de su universidad.

He probado la siguiente consulta :

```
select name,universidad,carrera,asignatura,cuatrimestre 
from users natural join unicars natural join asignaturas natural join 
carreras natural join unis order by cuatrimestre,asignatura asc;
```

pero me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
  +-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------+
    | name    | universidad              | carrera                | asignatura          | cuatrimestre |
    +---------+--------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------+
    | k1k4ss0 | Universidad de la Laguna | Ingenieria Informatica | Sistemas Operativos |            1 |
    +---------+--------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Lo que quiero es algo parecido a esto:

```
    +---------------------------------------------+--------------+
    | asignatura                                  | cuatrimestre |
    +---------------------------------------------+--------------+
    | Computabilidad y Algoritmia                 |            1 |
    | Estadistica                                 |            1 |
    | Estructura de Computadores                  |            1 |
    | Ingles Tecnico                              |            1 |
    | Sistemas Operativos                         |            1 |
    | Administracion de Sistemas                  |            2 |
    | Algoritmos y Estructuras de Datos Avanzadas |            2 |
    | Codigo Deontologico y Aspectos Legales      |            2 |
    | Fundamentos de Ingenieria del Software      |            2 |
    | Redes y Sistemas Distribuidos               |            2 |
    +---------------------------------------------+--------------+
    10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Con la diferencia de que muestre el nombre del usuario.

Comment: tus capturas de pantalla son muy difíciles de leer, no agregues así el contenido de ellas, edita esto y añádelo como texto

Comment: ok, dame un momento

Comment: Si, pero ademas quiero que se mueste el usuario, ya que el usuario tiene una universidad y una carrera asociada. En plan usuario |  lista de asignaturas | lista de cuatrimestres de las asignaturas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes hace uno de `JOIN` para traer los datos y puede ponerle un alias a las tablas para que se mas corta la consutla y mas legible:

```
select u.name as usuario,a. asignatura as asignatura, uni.cuatrimestre as cuatrimestre
from usuario a
inner join unicars uni on (uni.id_uni = u.id_uni) --aqui hacemos la union entre las tablas por su llave foranea
inner join asignaturas on (a.id=uni.id_asig) --aqui hacemos la union entre las tablas por su llave foranea
```

El nombre de la universidad no lo veo por ninguna parte

Comment: seguramente por que el OP olvidó poner esa tabla

Comment: Simplemente deje de ponerla, pero ahora la agrego

Comment: ya puse la tabla que faltaba

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo consegui. Tenia que usar el inner join, en vez del natural join. Tal y como dijiste

Comment: esta bien! saludos